# Call Taxonomy from .NetCore Blazor

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, sharepoint-rest-api, managed-metadata, taxonomy

I need to call the Sharepoint Taxonomy API. As CSOM is not available for .NetCore 3.0 I want to use the Taxonomy Internal Service Rest API: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server/ee588162(v=office.15)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

I tryed to use the `/_vti_bin/TaxonomyInternalService.json/PickSsps` API but can't find out what scope and resource I have to request the Access Token for. I always end up getting a 401 UNAUTHORIZED Error. Even if the Token is valid for other SharePoint Online APIs like `/_api/search/query?querytext='*'`

So my question is what Scope and Resource do I have to use for a valid AccessToken?

If there is a better way to call Taxonomy than using the internal API please also let me know. I know it's not optimal to use internal APIs but it seems to be the only possible way.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using app-only authentication. I'm not sure if that will work against the `TaxonomyInternalService` but if it does here's the scope you need:

`<AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/taxonomy" Right="Write" />`

Also you need to add `app@sharepoint` into the term store admins group.

But I do not recommend using `TaxonomyInternalService`. Instead I think you should try `client.svc` which is the back end for managed CSOM. This is actually a supported endpoint and should be better suited to get you what you need. The API is not at all straightforward so what I suggest is creating a full framework test CSOM app and Fiddling the traffic, or if you speak Node you can use [this](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp-taxonomy/docs/), and likewise Fiddle the traffic.  By the way the same scope and term store admin settings apply to this solution.

Good luck, this is a hard problem to solve.

Comment: I tryed to add app@sharepoint to my term store admins group but I get a error that says that no exact match is found.